# Implementing / registering an email sending client for windows

Tags: windows, email-client

I need to implement an email client that will be used only to send email. The problem I'm fecing is that the client needs to support sending attachments from Excel and PDFs from Edge, and finding information / figuring out the default email client registration seems to be quite difficult.

I found tool called [SetUserFTA](https://kolbi.cz/blog/2017/10/25/setuserfta-userchoice-hash-defeated-set-file-type-associations-per-user/) and registered notepad as the email client before proceeding further with my actual app to see that I will actually be able to accomplish this. And for edge, everything looks ok since I get this error and everything is as I expected:

[image]

But when I try from Excel, or even in windows explorer "Send to" -> "Mail recipient" I get this error:

> There is no email program associated to perform the requested action. Please install an email program, or if one is already installed, create an association in the Default Programs control panel.

But I have it as default app:

[image]

And also registered as mailto handled:

[image]

I tried to debug this with procmon by checking the registry keys read accessed when I try the sending, but I can't get anywhere from there, and there's so much totally irrelevant outlook problems etc. in the google results that I'm not able to find any useful info anymore.